# MySQL inner join matching on different fields

Tags: mysql

Write a query 
to use inner join of 
the
 Tables
 President
 and pres_term.   The join will be 
on 
pres_id
 in both tables and the query will print only the president’s first and last name, 
date of birth,
date of death, start and end dates in office
, and the reason that they left 
the office.  The joined query will match on president death and term end date

```
SELECT president.*, pres_term.* FROM president, pres_term INNER JOIN president
ON president.pres_id = pres_term.pres_id WHERE pres_term.term_end_date = president.death;
```

I can't get this query to work, have been messing with it for hours...
I don't know if there is something wrong with the tables or if it's just the query?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, modify your query to be like this:

```
SELECT
    president.*,
    pres_term.*
FROM
    president
INNER JOIN
    pres_term ON pres_term.pres_id = president.pres_id
WHERE
    pres_term.term_end_date = president.death;
```

The error you see is because you are referenced president table two times and the "select part" of the query results ambiguous